# Server-side validation of nonce in Sign in with Apple flow

Tags: ios, authentication, apple-sign-in

I am trying to understand Sign in with Apple. I am assuming a situation where there is an app server, an ios app and the apple authentication provider. In the WWDC 2020 session "Get the most out of Sign in with Apple" Apple has [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10173/?time=158) to say about the nonce value in the authorization request:

> But as we mentioned before, the request also has some properties that can help make the authorization process more secure. These are nonce and state.
>
> These properties will allow you to verify that the authorization and credential you get after executing a request are the ones you were expecting. Let's start by talking about what these properties are. The nonce is an opaque blob of data sent as a string in the request. It is important to generate one unique nonce every time you create a new request, as later on, you will be able to verify this value.
>
> In order to do that, the nonce value will be returned to you embedded in the identityToken property of the authorization credential.
>
> This will allow you to verify this value in your server, helping prevent replay attacks.

My understanding is: The app client creates an upredictable nonce for the authorization request sent to Apple's servers. If all goes well, Apple will return an identity token containing the same nonce. The client can check that the identity token contains the same nonce value that it included in the request, then go on sending that JWT to the application server which can use Apple's public key and the signature to make sure that the JWT is indeed signed by apple and be therefore sure that the user is who they claim to be.

But Apple says that

> This will allow you to verify this value in **your server**, helping prevent replay attacks.

(Emphasis mine)

In the flow I described my application server would not know the nonce, so it would not be able to verify anything about it. Is the suggestion here that the client requests a nonce (and a session id) from the application server first before creating an authorization request. Then sends that nonce as part of the authorization request, and later sends the JWT with the included nonce and the session id to the application server? So that the application server can also verify that the nonce is indeed the same one assigned at the start of the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could request a state and nonce from your server, but I would not because this is a possible attack vector.

It is better to generate the state and nonce in your app.  These are then included in the authentication request.

Once your app receives the response from Apple, it can verify that the state matches the state that it is expecting.

You then send the identity token and the expected nonce value to your server. The server validates that the JWT was signed by Apple and contains the expected nonce.

As an example of the flow you could use:

1. Your app sends the nonce to your server
2. Your server stores the nonce in an "active nonces" table
3. Once your app has received the identity token from Apple, it sends that to your server
4. Your server examines the token and extracts the nonce.
5. Your server confirms that the nonce is in the "active nonces" table.
6. If it is then it either deletes the nonce or flags it as "seen"
7. If it isn't then it rejects the authentication
8. If you elected to keep the nonce rather than deleting it you can periodically groom the table to clear out old records (say daily)

Comment: Thank you Paul! My question is exactly about this: "The server validates that the JWT was signed by Apple and contains the expected nonce." The nonce is generated by the app. How does the server know what nonce to expect?

Comment: As I said, you send it to your server when you send it the identity token. E.g. you could POST something like `{"identityToken":"eyX...","nonce":"abcd123"}`

Comment: Send it together? How does that prevent a replay attack? An attacker able to eavesdrop the identityToken would have that nonce, and could just send it to me again in the same POST request or? Then I would accept that replayed request based on the nonce in the JWT matching the separate nonce?

I would have to check uniquness of nonces at least per user for some expiration duration. But if I have that in place I also do not need to send the nonce explicitely anymore. Just checking that the nonce in the JWT is unique would be sufficient.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they have the nonce. They can't mint a signed JWT containing the nonce. The only thing that they could replay is another token from your app, but that token will have a different `sub` claim, so it's not like they can impersonate a different user. If you wanted to, you could send the nonce in a separate POST which your server then saves in an "active nonces" table.  Then when it decodes the JWT it can validate that the nonce is "active" and then delete the nonce.  You can also check the `iat` claim isn't too far in the past

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I have one last issue here. Let me try  like this:

Alice is using my app and sends the POST(jwt, nonce) you originally suggested to the app server. Bob is able to eavesdrop on the communication and has that POST request. Bob replays it to me, sending the exact same POST(jwt, nonce). Bob does not need to mint a new jwt, or send a different jwt. Just sends the exact same jwt he got from Alice with the exact same nonce.

Comment: Without any other uniqueness check my app server would:
- Believe that the jwt comes from Alice (sub is unchanged)
- Find that the nonce match (both the separate nonce and the nonce in the jwt match)
- The jwt is actually from apple (jwt is unchanged and was orignally signed by apple)
- iat is recent (if Bob is quick enough)

So my app server would believe that this is  from Alice and the replay attack would succeed.

What is the obvious point I am missing here?

Comment: That is addressed by my second suggestion. First send the nonce to your server, which is added to an "active nonce" database. Then you send the JWT. The server can check that the nonce in the JWT is in the "active nonce" database and remove it. Then when Bob attempts a replay the nonce is no longer in the table. You can also use the device check framework to protect the transactions so that Bob cannot use arbitrary code to send a nonce to your server.

Comment: Realistically, though, if Alice"s communications are compromised to the point where Bob can get the identity token that she is sending to your server then Bob can probably just get the access token you send back to Alice.

Comment: Right - I think that makes sense to me now. Thanks again! Will mark as answered